# Why do I get 'Inf' value while doing quantile mapping in MATLAB?

Tags: distributions, matlab, gamma-distribution, inverse-gamma-distribution, quantiles

I am doing bias correction of rainfall data simulated by Global Climate Model.
Since, rainfall data generally follows `gamma distribution`, I am estimating parameter for gamma distribution for the time series of daily rainfall of observed period (Jan 1971, Jan 1972, Jan 1973, ...., Jan 2005) and then taking the `gamma inverse` of CDF of rainfall time series of projected period (Jan 2010, Jan 2011, Jan 2012, ...., Jan 2039). Since, it is the timeseries of daily rainfall for specif months it has many zero values.

Though I get the reasonable values for majority of grids, few grids show `Inf` value which is wrong.

Why is this happening? I have also tried the same thing in `R` using `qmap` package but that also gave `NA` values for some grid.

Can I use some flag where I get `Inf` value and replace it with some large value from observed timeseries?

I also get such warnings while running code in MATLAB, I guess this is where it places `Inf` values

> Warning: GAMINV did not converge for a = 0.0642935, b = 17.8865, p =
>   3.35539e-24.

Comment: The error message you describe means that Matlab could not find parameters of the inverse gamma distribution which fit your data well enough. As there is no analytical method (="mathematical formula") known which finds the inverse gamma, Matlab has to resort to iteratively "tune" the  "parameter knobs" until it finds parameter values which "fit" to the data. It couldn't find "good" parameters in your case. You could manually check some of the offending data sets to see if for these gamma parameters are estimated which are very "odd" or "different" than for non-offending datasets. ...

Comment: ... If you find that for the offending data sets the estimated gamma parameters are somehow different (meaning that these data sets then provide "unusual" input to GAMINV), you could include that into this answer by [edit]ing it. Better yet, if you could provide code as a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which reproduces the problem, helping would be easier

Comment: Although the symptoms described here are a matter of software implementation, behind them is a statistical issue concerning how problematic it can be to try to fit a continuous distribution to a dataset full of zeros.  Consider editing your post to focus on that: namely, rather than asking how to resolve the computational errors that signal a faulty statistical procedure, ask instead about good ways to go about modeling your data.